# High voltage/current design on PCB

Tags: pcb, ac, eaglecad, high-voltage

I am building a circuit that allows me to control a set of light (more specifically Christmas lights you see in supermarkets) with relays (AQH 2223). My idea is to have the controller input on one side and the light on the opposite side. An example would be something like this.

[image: Example of the circuit]

My problem is that I don't know the exact trace dimension I need to the light circuits such that I don't melt the board over a long period of use (around 30 minutes). What are some typical trace dimension values for household appliances? Also, are there libraries for AC outlets? I am planning on using something like this.

[image: Example of the outlet]

I want to mount AC outlets on the PCB but so far I haven't find any libraries for eagle yet and I am quite sure that people have done this before. I am fairly new to Eagle so sorry if this kind of question has been asked before. Thanks!

Comment: Almost any trace calculator can tell you that. OTOH you need to worry about creepage, and that can be a bit trickier.

Comment: Why do you need a library in order to use a part? Most parts that mount on a PC board have manufacturer recommended footprints right in their data sheets. Make your own symbol for the part.

Comment: In your schematic you should move the 1K resistor from the source side of the FET to the drain side. This is highly preferable because it will still limit the LED current by the same amount. This change will also stop causing the turn on voltage of the FET, w.r.t. GND, from changing as the LED current is switched on and off.

Comment: @MichaelKaras I wanted to use a library because I wasn't sure how to make my own symbol (I am new to Eagle so I am not sure how to make something custom). Thanks for the datasheet as well.

Comment: Let me bring you into a little secret about libraries....very often it is necessary to modify library entries because they do not match to the part design OR they require adjustment against the process parameters used by your selected PC board fab house. So unless you feel like spinning your prototype board an extra time, just to adjust the footprints, it behooves you to check the footprint decals for each and every part type on your board against the manufacturer's data sheets.

Answer (score 2):

The part that you pictured is not suitable for mounting on a PC board. If you must mount an AC plug on a PC board you should consider using a PC mount style that has through hole type connections so as to be rugged.

Any circuit board that has exposed AC connections needs to be properly packaged and enclosed to make it safe to use and operate.

One NEMA style outlet suitable for PC board mounting is the TE part number 213598-2.

[image]

You can find the complete drawing data sheet (with footprint) at the [TE Web Site](http://www.te.com/catalog/pn/en/213598-2?RQPN=213598-2).

Good old Mouser has [plenty of those in stock.](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/TE-Connectivity/3-213598-2/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvE0yU1RFqi7SH7Yo27/YlDluplbI4jXiE=) *(509 at time of edit)*